# Term to represent "prejudice against ugly people" or "favouritism towards beautiful people"?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, I have been noticing (disturbingly of late) that there is a lot of favouritism being shown towards beautiful people in all walks of life. One of the most visible of such fields is all forms of advertising where we rarely see ugly people being hired for promoting a product or a service unless of course, they are the target audience.

Is there a term to denote such *prejudice against ugly people* or *favouritism towards beautiful people* much like "racism" has come to denote "prejudice directed against someone of a different race"?

I have Googled a lot of phrases which can denote such a phenomenon, but haven't been able to find an appropriate term to represent it, much less know if it exists at all.

Comment: How about "real life"?

Comment: :) Witty but not what I am looking for!

Comment: Do "shallow" or "superficial" not work for you? Beauty is, as the saying goes, only skin deep.

Comment: Any different than preference for beautiful things (other than people)?

Answer (score 6):

[Lookism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookism) is often used to describe *appearance-based discrimination*:

> Lookism is a term used to refer to the positive stereotypes, prejudice, and preferential treatment given to physically attractive people, or more generally to people whose appearance matches cultural preferences. The pejorative term **body fascism** is also used as a synonym and Warren Farrell has proposed the term **genetic celebrity** to describe adoration of the attractive.

I've also seen the term *beauty bias* bandied about every now and then in discussions about the [physical attractiveness stereotype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_attractiveness_stereotype), "*a term that psychologists use to refer to the tendency to assume that people who are physically attractive also possess other socially desirable personality traits*". In other words, being beautiful can also be a disadvantage (which is the exact opposite of your contention).

Comment: Could you revert your incorrect revert of "of late" in the question please?

Comment: @deadly Done. Whoopsie.

Comment: Is that still in popular use? I haven't heard this ridiculous word since the very early 1990's.

Comment: @Kaz [Yes, it is](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lookism%2CLookism&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) :)

Comment: @coleopterist Hey, the timeline of the *rise* of that word according to Ngram is exactly where I would put it if I were to guess. The decline since the mid 1990's makes sense, but probably the main reason I haven't heard it is: getting out of university. :)

Comment: @Kaz :) Check the WP link in my answer and delight in the "Fat Acceptance Movement"! (Some of the decline in the ngram is also due to Google's corpus which is apparently not as well populated post 2000)

Comment: A simple Google search turned up _lookism_ used in [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2033782/Didnt-job-Blame-lookism-discrimination-ugly-new-racism.html).

Answer (score 3):

As @coleopterist says, there's *lookism*. But I'd never heard of it before, and the meaning wouldn't necessarily be obvious to me unless context made it clear - even though it does follow the normal pattern (*sexism, racism, ageism*, etc., where the actual attribute preceding *-ism* is "neutral").

So although it's less prevalent (only 6K hits in Google, as opposed to 160K for *lookism*), I think...

> [uglyism](http://www.aboutequalopportunities.co.uk/uglyism-discrimination.html) *- a form of discrimination based on people’s physical beauty [or lack thereof]*

...has something to commend it. I hadn't heard of that either, but it seemed a natural word to search for, and I wasn't surprised to find plenty of references. For example, the [huffingtonpost](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2008/10/30/ugliness-is-examined-in-s_n_139204.html) uses it, and plenty of people read that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if these are commonly known but here are a couple of terms:

> *[appearance bias](http://www.pgpmediation.com/2011/02/11/appearance-bias/)*
>
> *[beauty bias](http://www.theglasshammer.com/news/2012/01/05/ending-the-beauty-bias/)*

The sources I have linked may not be very helpful, but I hope the terms convey the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Followers of the political correctness movement usually believe in the doctrine that discrimination comes from fear, and so then various *-phobia* words are used to denote discriminations. For example, hatred of homosexuals is really a fear, hence *homophobia*. With that in mind, is there a word that refers to fear of ugliness or ugly people? Evidently, yes: *cacophobia*.